# return modified values of Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am a newbie of JavaScript and trying to learn promises.

I learned that `Promise.all()` [waits for all fulfillments (or the first rejection)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

I also learned that `.then()` is able to return modified content as return values, to promises.

I am trying to see if there is a way to modify values from individual promises, as there isn't any examples in that promise documentation.

In the following example, I have two individual promises `p1,p2` and the `p3` resolves them all and I am trying to return the values of `p1, p2` in `p3` but all I got is `Promise { <pending> }`

```
const _ = require('lodash');

var p1 = Promise.resolve(1);
var p2 = Promise.resolve(2);
var p3 = Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(
    values => {
        return _.map(values, function(a){return a+1});
});
//If I output the value of `p3` it does not give me the value of [2,3]
console.log(p3);
```

How can I change the return so that I can get something as `[2,3]`?

Comment: `p3.then(console.log);`

Comment: @4castle thank you. I know by 'console.log' I am able to see the values, but  the return value is still a promise

Comment: You will have to put your code that depend on promise in the `.then`. Otherwise you could use async, await, but it is hardly supported

Comment: yes it will be a promise - because asynchronous code is asynchronous, and you can't get the value in a synchronous way, because Promises do not make asynchronous code synchronous

Comment: @Akxe that's exactly what I did: I put my code in `.then`

Comment: @JaromandaX but the `.all()` waits all promises to resolve before heading into '.then()'. Isn't this supposed to be synchronous?

Comment: No it is not synchronous

Comment: @JaromandaXif I have many promises and each has a value (Let's assume we need to process each one of them using the same function). In this scenario, how can I do to perform a task that does: wait and resolve every promise and return modified data in an array?

Comment: the results are available inside the `Promise.all(promises).then(results => /* here results are available */)` - outside of that, they are not available - as stated by @Akxe *you will **have to** put your code that depend on promise in the `.then`*

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you. I see your point. I recall seeing some source code that uses `Promise.all().then()` which returns the content in the `.then()`. Not sure how that works. Please comment if you think of anything. Thanks!

Comment: `Not sure how that works` - poorly :p